# combine multiple pdfs(using url path) using tool like iText for dot net

Tags: pdfsharp

Ho can I combine multiple pdfs(using url path) into one using tool like iText.
I am able to combine pdfsfrom my c# code using iText when the files are stored on my hard disk(local path).
But unable to combine when I am given the url to pdfs.
Thanks in advance
-Naresh

Comment: Could you grab them via URL, save them to the hard drive, then combine them?

Answer (score 1):

The PDF files must be downloaded in order to be combined.

So the question is: who will download the files, your app or the lib you are using?

PDFsharp cannot download PDF files from URLs yet. This could be implemented but I think it doesn't make much sense; you're much more flexible if you download the PDF files with your own code, retrying the download if it failed if you want.

Downloading them to MemoryStreams will do, no need to create temporary files.

I don't know if iText or iTextSharp will do the download for you.